# Plotly Error: X-axis of scatter is grouping time series points erroneously

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python, streamlit

## TL;DR

I am plotting time series data using a plotly scatter plot in a streamlit dashboard. The data is captured every second (actually down to microseconds) but the plot groups approximately every two minutes of data together.

### Improper "grouped every 2 minute" output

Plotly express in a streamlit dashboard

[image: Actual output]

### Code

```
fig = px.scatter(df,
         x='dateTime',
         y='currentHeading')
fig.update_yaxes(
    scaleanchor="x",
    scaleratio=1)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M:%S")
```

### Expected output

Matplotlib in a jupyter notebook:

[image: Expected output]

### Is the data the issue? Seemingly not

Here is the output of a plotly express line plot, the points are spaced along the x-axis appropriately.

[image: Plotly line works correctly]